# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::makeAllSearchable() Laravel Scout Algolia

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, algolia, laravel-scout

I am just starting to use Laravel Scout and Angolia driver. I had a problem with importing the model. At first, I import the App\Agency and it was imported. But when I try to import the rest of my model, it produces an error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::makeAllSearchable()`

1st import

```
 php artisan scout:import "App\Agency"
 Imported [App\Agency] models up to ID: 3
 All [App\Agency] records have been imported.
```

and another import

```
php artisan scout:import "App\Bag"
[BadMethodCallException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::makeAllSearchable()
```

I put the use Searchable; in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got the solution. I need to declare Laravel\Scout\Searchable and add use Searchable in every model